# Undefined references to OpenGL on Ubuntu

Tags: opengl, cmake, glut, freeglut

I'm getting all these undefined references:

```
Linking CXX executable SimpleGavam
../../lib/local/Gavam/libGavam.a(MeshUtils.cpp.o): In function `Gavam::DrawMesh(cv::Mat_<float>&, cv::Mat_<float> const&, cv::Mat_<int> const&, cv::Vec<double, 6> const&, double, double, double, double, cv::Size_<int> const&, double, double)':
/home/samuel/Clm-Z/lib/local/Gavam/src/MeshUtils.cpp:189: undefined reference to `glutSwapBuffers'
../../lib/local/Gavam/libGavam.a(MeshUtils.cpp.o): In function `Gavam::InitialiseOpenGLDrawingWindow(int, int, double, double, double)':
/home/samuel/Clm-Z/lib/local/Gavam/src/MeshUtils.cpp:578: undefined reference to `glutInit'
/home/samuel/Clm-Z/lib/local/Gavam/src/MeshUtils.cpp:580: undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
/home/samuel/Clm-Z/lib/local/Gavam/src/MeshUtils.cpp:582: undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
/home/samuel/Clm-Z/lib/local/Gavam/src/MeshUtils.cpp:584: undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
/home/samuel/Clm-Z/lib/local/Gavam/src/MeshUtils.cpp:585: undefined reference to `glutHideWindow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [exe/SimpleGavam/SimpleGavam] Error 1
make[1]: *** [exe/SimpleGavam/CMakeFiles/SimpleGavam.dir/all] Error 2
```

I'm using cmake to compile my project and I've added the glut flags in `CMakeLists`

```
SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -std=c++11 -lGL -lglut -lGLU")
SET( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -g -std=c++11 -lGL -lglut -lGLU")
```

I have these includes in the files:

```
#include <Gavam.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>

// OPEN GL
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just FYI: GLUT is not part of OpenGL. It's often installed alongside OpenGL and there's documentation on in on opengl.org, but its not part of the specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the linker flags, use CMake Standard Module [FindOpenGL](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#module%3aFindOpenGL)

Comment: I have add this, find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)

include_directories(library ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS})

Comment: Also add target_link_libraries(target_name ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARIES})